# Logging in a GrailsUnitTestCase?

Tags: unit-testing, logging, grails, groovy

How do I setup logging in a grails unit-test?

When I try `log.info` or `log.debug`, the `.txt` output files are empty, even after I tried adding a console appender. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help, it's taken from the 1.2 release notes

> By default, grails does not show the
>   output from your tests. You can make
>   it do so by passing -echoOut and/or
>   -echoErr to test-app:
>
> grails test-app -echoOut -echoErr

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work.  I always have to go to the reports to get the error output.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That makes "--Output from testSomething--" in the test output, but it doesn't actually display the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend `GrailsUnitTestCase`, you ought to be able to use `mockLogging()`, but the appenders you set up in Grails config won't be applied in a unit test, which works in isolation from the real framework. They'd only be available in integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to use mockLogging in grails 1.3.7 with GrailsUnitTestCase either.  I think there is probably a bug and it may work in Grails 2.0.  Here is what I did to work around it:

```
class Foo {
    String name

    Long invokeLogTest(String key) {
        if (key.empty) {
            log.error("key was sent as empty string")
            return 10
        }  
    }
}

void testErrorCase() {
    def f = new Foo(name:'jp')
    f.metaClass.log = [error:{}]
    assert 10 == f.invokeLogTest("")
}
```